# Sort sibling <div>s with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm banging my head with the problem that has more to do with 2nd grade mathematics than programming. Here goes: four `<div>` elements are placed one after another, horizontally. When you click one, script places it in front. You click another one, and it's also placed in front, etc. You get the picture. Now, what I'd like to do is to sort remaining `<div>` elements (all but the first one) using original order.

Maybe this pic will make things clear:

[image]

After step #3, `C` should be placed after `B`, so it should go like this: `D A B C`.

Here's a sample code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>mixit</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .insidebox{
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      line-height: 50px;
      margin: 0 0 0 20px;
      text-align: center;
      float: left;
      border: black solid 3px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="a" class="insidebox">A</div>
      <div id="b" class="insidebox">B</div>
      <div id="c" class="insidebox">C</div>
      <div id="d" class="insidebox">D</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I understand that I can use `.insertAfter()` to place element in front, but how should I tackle the sorting part? The keyword is *initial order*, not alphabetical order. Letters and boxes are given just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: I could've posted a smaller diagram, though... =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
var $initial = $('.insidebox');
$('.insidebox').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.parent()
         .prepend($this)
         .append( $initial.not(this) );
});
```

You store the initial list and on each click re append it (*excluding the current one*)

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Dyafx/

---

**update**

Hell.. you do not even need to prepend the current element.. when you append the rest they will go after the clicked one anyway ..

```
var $initial = $('.insidebox');
$('.insidebox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent()
         .append( $initial.not(this) );
});
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Dyafx/1/

Comment: Dude, if only we had PayPal in Serbia, I'd buy one hell of a beer! You saved the day! Thanks with sugar on top!

Comment: lol.. mental beer is ok too.. thanks :) (*and you are welcome*)

Comment: +1, good solution. I didn't think that it was so simple (code-wise).

Comment: The equiv of beer for an answer that is correct and has helped you is to accept the answer, its good for your stats and for his reputation.

Comment: I already upvoated, checked and twitted a permalink to his answer. But, damn, the guy deserves a beer for this one! (and Serbs deserve PayPal) =)

Answer (score 1):

Store the initial order as an array. Then sort by array index- the first one (A) will have array index 1, etc.

Comment: That was my initial idea - to save index using `.data()` and retrieve it later. But how should I sort *only* the remaining `<div>`s, without the first one?

Comment: @aL3xa: After you prepended the first div, you should be able to use `$(this).nextAll()`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container div").click(function(){
       $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

cheers.

Comment: Yup, but that doesn't sort the remaining divs. And perhaps you meant `$(#container>div")`?

Comment: Hi aLexa, Could you please give me some example for which my solution doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: Your code leaves the elements in the order `D C A B` after the second click, where the OP wants `D A B C`. Read the question carefully.

Comment: the OP want the remaining elements to be re-sorted according to how they were when the page was loaded.